# How to get the value of a <td> with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I want to do is when I double click on a cell a textbox appears to update the cell data. Then I want to get the value updated. For now I tried this :

```
     $('#previsionnel td').dblclick(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var input = $('<input>', {
            value: $this.text(),
            type: 'text',
            blur: function () {
                 $this.text(this.value);
            },
            keyup: function (e) {
                if (e.which === 13)
                    input.blur();
            }
        }).appendTo($this.empty()).focus();

        var test = $this.find("input").val();
        console.log(test);

        $('#previsionnel td').change(function () {
            console.log(test);
        });
    });
```

Everything works, except I just can't get the data updated with `$(this).text()` In my console log the result is empty.

Some screenshots of what is supposed to do :

[image: Data]

[image: DoubleClick]

[image: DataUpdated]

[image: ConsoleLog]

As you can see in the last screenshot, the second value in the console must be 5000 and not 100000.00.

Comment: Please add your html

Comment: $(this).text(this.value); will probably not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: please provide your html

Comment: My html table is basically empty. I populate it with AJAX requests but I got only one column so it's like `<tr> <td> 5000 </td> </tr>` several times.

Comment: In the `blur` event, `this` refers to the `input` not the `td`.  Use `$(this).closest("td").text($(this).val());$(this).hide();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to use `$(this).val()` in the function below:

```
blur: function() {
  $(this).val(this.text);
},
```

Second, Because your `input` is a child of `td` then use `.find("input")` as in:

```
var test = $(this).find("input").val();
```

I've also moved your `.change()` function out of your `.dblclick()`. Reason is that the above "test" variable will only be set when you double click the td, not when you change it.

```js
$('#previsionnel td').dblclick(function() {
  var input = $('<input>', {
    value: $(this).text(),
    type: 'text',
    blur: function() {
      $(this).val(this.text);
    },
    keyup: function(e) {
      if (e.which === 13)
        input.blur();
    }
  }).appendTo($(this).empty()).focus();

  var test = $(this).find("input").val();
  console.log(test);
  $('#previsionnel td').change(function() {

    test = $(this).find("input").val();
    console.log(test);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="previsionnel">
  <tr>
    <td>something</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried your `var test = $(this).find("input").val();` and I have the right  value when I double click on it. When I change its value, I have the value of an other row. I tried your blur function as well but it wasn't working so I let it like before.

Comment: @HoareauThomas Check the snippet again, i changed it again to the change function work for the correct td

Comment: It works, I didn't think about that while it makes sense. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

1) There is syntax error  - unclosed handler `dblclick`

```
 $('#previsionnel td').dblclick(function () {
            var input = $('<input>', {
                value: $(this).text(),
                type: 'text',
                blur: function () {
                    $(this).text(this.value);
                },
                keyup: function (e) {
                    if (e.which === 13)
                        input.blur();
                }
            }).appendTo($(this).empty()).focus();

            var test = $(this).text();
            console.log(test);

            $('#previsionnel td').change(function () {
                console.log(test);
            });
});
```

2) If you use AJAX logic for getting data in the table, try to use event handler `on();`. Because

> 'Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.'

E.g.

```
$('body').on('dblclick', '#previsionnel td', function () {
            var input = $('<input>', {
                value: $(this).text(),
                type: 'text',
                blur: function () {
                    $(this).text(this.value);
                },
                keyup: function (e) {
                    if (e.which === 13)
                        input.blur();
                }
            }).appendTo($(this).empty()).focus();

            var test = $(this).text();
            console.log(test);

            $('#previsionnel td').change(function () {
                console.log(test);
            });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line `$(this).val(this.text);` `this` refers to the text box. I am guessing you want to update the td? Try the below snippet

```js
$('#previsionnel td').on( "dblclick", function() {
  var input = $('<input>', {
    value: $(this).text(),
    type: 'text',
    blur: function() {
      $(this).parent("td").text($(this).val());
      $(this).hide();
    },
    keyup: function(e) {
      if (e.which === 13)
        input.blur();
    }
  }).appendTo($(this).empty()).focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="previsionnel">
  <tr>
    <td>something</td>
    <td>something2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input; // Please declare input as globaly declare
   $('#previsionnel td').dblclick(function () {
            var test;
            input = $('<input>', {
                value: $(this).text(),
                type: 'text',
                blur: function () {
                   test = $(this).text(this.value);
                },
                keyup: function (e) {
                    if (e.which === 13)
                        input.blur();
                }
            }).appendTo($(this).empty()).focus();

            var test = $(input).val();//use input variable instead this
            console.log(test);            
         });   
         $(document).on('blur','input',function () {
             console.log($(this).val()); //get value outside event listener
         });
```